# Angular Crud App Subscribe don't exist on void type

Tags: angular

I'm building an app using an Angular crud tutorial. and I'm getting this error message: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.ts(2339)  I thought it was because I was in strict mode but when I changed it to false the error is still present.

````
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { InvestorService } from '../investor.service';
import { Investor } from '../investor.model';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-investor',
  templateUrl: './list-investor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-investor.component.scss']
})
export class ListInvestorComponent implements OnInit {
  Investors: Investor[] = [];

  constructor(private investorService: InvestorService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.investorService.getInvestorList().subscribe ((res) => {
      this.Investors = res.map( (e) => {
        return {
          _id: e.payload.doc.id,
          get id(){
            return this. _id;
          },
          set id(value) {
            this. _id = value;
          },
          ...(e.payload.doc.data() as Investor),
        };
      });
    });
  }

  removeInvestor = (investor: Investor) =>
  this.investorService.deleteInvestor(investor);

}```
````

Comment: To subscribe your ```getInvestorList()``` must return an **Observable** like ```getInvestorList():Observable<any>```.

Comment: @dmitryro not going to lie, I don't quite understand what you mean. I place the: Observable into the code but then the entire section became an error.

Comment: You have to build your method in service in a way that will return **Observable** and not **void** - now it returns **void** and it makes subscription impossible. Read [Obserables](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable).

Comment: Can you update the question with how you wrote `getInvestorList()`? with the return type

Comment: @Timmy so, after placing the `:Observable` into the code, then the entire section became an error. Then I am guessing that you are not returning anything from that method!!!

Comment: could you share your getInvestorList() method code?